# ¿Cómo puedo poner caracteres tales como el ruso o el chino en un JLabel?

Tags: java, java-swing, internacionalización

Mi problema es el siguiente, al cambiar de idioma sea **francés, portugués, inglés, etc.**, lo hace satisfactoriamente, sin embargo al intentar cambiarlo a ruso o chino no es así.
Las opciones del menú son **JLabel** y es con este con el que da problemas. En versiones anteriores estas opciones eran **JMenuItems** y todo funcionaba bien. Por eso quería saber si hay una línea de código o clase que se usa para permitir que estos caracteres puedan ser ingresados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. En la aplicación uso varios [archivo-de-propiedades](/questions/tagged/archivo-de-propiedades) (.properties) con los textos de esta y su idioma correspondiente, y al colocarlo en cualquier jlabel pasa lo antes mencionado.  Esto es lo que tengo en el fichero que contiene al chino, similar a lo que tiene el ruso:

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Lrj.png[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida, tu pregunta aunque válida es muy amplia; la idea del sitio es mostrar lo que haz intentado y las dudas especificas que haz tenido, como tal ahorita es muy amplia y podría terminar cerrada checa por favor como preguntar [ask] del mismo modo si aun no lo haces realiza el recorrido [tour]

Comment: O sea dejame resumirte, lo que necesito saber no es que programen todo una clase con el código, sino si el JLabel tiene un método que se encargue de permitirme ingresar caracteres rusos o chinos y ¿cuál es?. O si pueden hacer un link a una página mucho mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes poner caracteres en ruso o Chino si utilizas Unicode en el texto de tu label.

Por ejemplo. El siguiente código imprime un carácter en chino en un Label de un dialogo.

```
public class Ejemplo {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      // en uniconde 8FCA es un código de caracter chino el escape \u
      // indica que el texto es uniconde.
      f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("\u8FCA" ));
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

---

Con lo agregado debo decirte que lo de los archivos properties para los idiomas es lo correcto.

En el siguiente ejemplo estoy mostrando un combo donde muestro la palabra hola en varios idiomas (lo comento para que sirva de muestra a alguna otra persona que tenga duda y quiera ver un ejemplo completo).

```
public class EjemploIdioma {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // se obtiene el idioma local
      Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

      // se carga el recurso del directorio i18n todos los recursos inician con el
      // prefijo i18n
      ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n/i18n", locale);
      final JFrame f = new JFrame();

      // se indica que el frame estará dividido en regiones (norte, sur, este, oeste y centro
      ((JPanel) f.getContentPane()).setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // se agrega una etiqueta fija a la region norte
      f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Ponga un texto"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

      // se crea un combo con los codigos de idioma y lenguajes soportados
      final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new String[]{
     "es_ES",
      "es_MX",
      "en_US",
      "fr_FR",
      // este es el chino
      "zh_CN",
      // este es el ruso
      "ru_RU"
      });

      // se carga una propertie en una etiqueta inicialmente
      final JLabel etiquetaConLeyenda = new JLabel(rb.getString("leyenda"));

      // se agrega un evento al combo para que al elegir un nuevo código de idioma-pais
      combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     // este evento cambia el idioma en que se presenta la etiqueta
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Cambiando por " + combo.getSelectedItem() + "");
        String texto = combo.getSelectedItem() + "";
        int indice = texto.indexOf('_');
        String idioma = texto.substring(0, indice);
        String pais = texto.substring(indice + 1);
        System.err.println(" idioma " + idioma + " pais " + pais);

        // se genera un Locale con los datos del idioma y el pais
        Locale locale = new Locale(idioma, pais);

        // se vuelve a recuperar el ResourceBundle
        ResourceBundle rbInterno = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n/i18n", locale);
        System.out.println("el locale es " + locale);

        // se imprime el texto en consola para verificar que se ha leido correctamente
        System.out.println("El texto es " + rbInterno.getString("leyenda"));

        // se asigna el nuevo texto a la etiqueta
        etiquetaConLeyenda.setText(rbInterno.getString("leyenda"));

        // se repinta la pantalla
        f.repaint();
     }
      });

      // se agrega el combo de seleccion de idioma al centro del frame
      f.getContentPane().add(combo, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      //se agrega la leyenda traducida en la parte infrerior de la pantalla
      f.getContentPane().add(etiquetaConLeyenda, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // se centra el frame
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

      // se auto ajusta la pantalla
      f.pack();
      // se pone si visible la pantalla
      f.setVisible(true);

      // se indica que al cerrar el frame se termina la aplicación
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   }

}
```

En un directorio llamado i18n tengo todos los archivos de idioma

```
i18n  <- directorio
   i18n.properties         <- he puesto lo mismo que en español de españa
   i18n_en_US.properties   <- ingles estadounidense
   i18n_es_ES.properties   <- español de España
   i18n_es_MX.properties   <- español de México
   i18n_fr_FR.properties   <- frances
   i18n_ru_RU.properties   <- ruso
   i18n_zh_CN.properties   <- chino
```

[image: Directorios archivos i18n]

El último archivo es el del chino y el penúltimo es el del ruso.

En el archivo properties del chino tengo:

```
leyenda=\u4f60\u597d
```

En el archivo properties del ruso tengo:

```
leyenda=\u0417\u0434\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435
```

En el archivo properties del frances tengo:

```
leyenda=Salut
```

En el archivo properties del español mexicano tengo:

```
leyenda=\u00bfQu\u00e9 onda?
```

En el archivo properties del español de España tengo:

```
leyenda=Hola
```

La ejecución para el ruso es:
 [image: ejecución en ruso]

La ejecución para el chino es:
 [image: ejecución en chino]

Espero que lo que te he puesto te ayude con tu problema si no es así entonces es necesario ver tu código para ayudarte.

Comment: Edité la pregunta para que observes lo que me pasa.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta mostrando un ejemplo completo. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: El problema que tenia es que le estaba dando fuente(Tw Cen Condensed) a los jlabel y cuando lo traducía al chino o al ruso daba problemas. Muchas gracias